# Complex JSON to multiple mssql tables

Tags: c#, json.net

Task: Insert the JSON response into multiple mssql tables

Problem: The job takes forever.

Current status:

I get the following content response from an API:

```json
[{
        "About": "",
        "Name": "Employee_1",
        "EmployeeId": "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee",
        "Address1": "Empstreet 4, 3. floor",
        "Phone": "90909090",
        "Birthdate": "1980-01-21",
        "City": "Empcity",
        "Zip": "8989",
        "Competencies": [{
            "Name": "Tablet",
            "ShortCode": "TAB",
            "Status": false
        }, {
            "Name": "Flex",
            "ShortCode": "FLX",
            "Status": false
        }],
        "CustomColumns": [{
            "Description": "",
            "Name": "",
            "Type": "CheckBox",
            "Value": "False"
        }],
        "CustomRoles": [{
            "CustomRoleModels": [{
                "IsAdminRole": false,
                "IsEmployeeRole": false,
                "IsPlannerRole": true,
                "Name": "Shop Manager"
            }],
            "DepartmentId": "49664884-8382-4712-9953-fb36ca13fd1b"
        }],
        "HistoricalWages": [{
            "StartDate": "2000-01-01",
            "Wage": 120
        }],
        "NotAvailable": [{
            "From": "12:00",
            "To": "05:00",
            "WeekDayIndex": 1
        }, {
            "From": "12:00",
            "To": "04:00",
            "WeekDayIndex": 0
        }, {
            "From": "12:00",
            "To": "03:00",
            "WeekDayIndex": 4
        }, {
            "From": "12:00",
            "To": "05:00",
            "WeekDayIndex": 3
        }],
        "Notes": [{
            "Author": "4a408a58-f9d6-4898-80a5-c3ef5667d2c6",
            "Comment": "",
            "Date": "2016-03-17"
        }],
        "Roles": [{
            "Admin": false,
            "DepartmentId": "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee",
            "Employee": true,
            "Planner": false
        }]
    }, {
        "About": "",
        "Name": "Employee_2",
        "EmployeeId": "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-ffffffffffff",
        "Address1": "Empstreet 5, 3. floor",
        "Phone": "80808080",
        "Birthdate": "1981-01-21",
        "City": "Empcity",
        "Zip": "8987",
        "Competencies": [{
            "Name": "Tablet",
            "ShortCode": "TAB",
            "Status": false
        }, {
            "Name": "Flex",
            "ShortCode": "FLX",
            "Status": false
        }],
        "CustomColumns": [{
            "Description": "",
            "Name": "",
            "Type": "CheckBox",
            "Value": "False"
        }],
        "CustomRoles": [{
            "CustomRoleModels": [{
                "IsAdminRole": false,
                "IsEmployeeRole": false,
                "IsPlannerRole": true,
                "Name": "Shop Manager"
            }],
            "DepartmentId": "49664884-8382-4712-9953-fb36ca13fd1b"
        }],
        "HistoricalWages": [{
            "StartDate": "2000-01-01",
            "Wage": 120
        }],
        "NotAvailable": [{
            "From": "12:00",
            "To": "05:00",
            "WeekDayIndex": 1
        }, {
            "From": "12:00",
            "To": "04:00",
            "WeekDayIndex": 0
        }, {
            "From": "12:00",
            "To": "03:00",
            "WeekDayIndex": 4
        }, {
            "From": "12:00",
            "To": "05:00",
            "WeekDayIndex": 3
        }],
        "Notes": [{
            "Author": "4a408a58-f9d6-4898-80a5-c3ef5667d2c6",
            "Comment": "",
            "Date": "2016-03-17"
        }],
        "Roles": [{
            "Admin": false,
            "DepartmentId": "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee",
            "Employee": true,
            "Planner": false
        }]
    }]
```

And from that i have made the following Classes

```cs
public class Competency
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ShortCode { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
    }

public class CustomColumn
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class CustomRoleModel
{
    public bool IsAdminRole { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmployeeRole { get; set; }
    public bool IsPlannerRole { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CustomRole
{
    public List<CustomRoleModel> CustomRoleModels { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

public class HistoricalWage
{
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public int Wage { get; set; }
}

public class NotAvailable
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public int WeekDayIndex { get; set; }
}

public class Note
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public bool Admin { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public bool Employee { get; set; }
    public bool Planner { get; set; }
}

public class Employees
{
    public string About { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Birthdate { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public List<Competency> Competencies { get; set; }
    public List<CustomColumn> CustomColumns { get; set; }
    public List<CustomRole> CustomRoles { get; set; }
    public List<HistoricalWage> HistoricalWages { get; set; }
    public List<NotAvailable> NotAvailable { get; set; }
    public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON content is stored in a variable named 'json' and are deserialized into above classes classes as follows:

```cs
List<Employees> employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employees>>(json);
```

With the newly created object below function is called

```cs
private static void InsertDataToEmployees(List<Employees> allEmployees)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["msEmployees"].ConnectionString;
    List<Employees> records = allEmployees;

    string insert_employee = "INSERT INTO dbo.dtEmployees (Name, EmployeeId, Address1, Phone, Birthdate, City, Zip) " +
        " VALUES (@Name, @EmployeeId, @Address1, @Phone, @Birthdate, @City, @Zip)";

    string insert_competencies = "INSERT INTO dbo.dtCompetencies (EmployeeId, Name, ShortCode, Status) " +
        " VALUES (@EmployeeId, @Name, @ShortCode, @Status)";

    string insert_available = "INSERT INTO dbo.dtAvailable (EmployeeId, [From], [To], WeekDayIndex) " +
        " VALUES (@EmployeeId, @From, @To, @WeekDayIndex)";

    string insert_roles = "INSERT INTO dbo.dtRoles (EmployeeId, Admin, DepartmentId, Employee, Planner) " +
        " VALUES (@EmployeeId, @Admin, @DepartmentId, @Employee, @Planner)";

    string insert_wages = "INSERT INTO dbo.dtWages (EmployeeId, StartDate, Wage) " +
        " VALUES (@EmployeeId, @StartDate, @Wage)";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        foreach (var employee in allEmployees)
        {
            string empID = employee.EmployeeId;

            using (SqlCommand cmd_employees = new SqlCommand(insert_employee, conn))
            {
                    cmd_employees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", (object)employee.Name ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_employees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", (object)employee.EmployeeId ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_employees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", (object)employee.Address1 ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_employees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", (object)employee.Phone ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_employees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthdate", (object)employee.Birthdate ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_employees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", (object)employee.Zip ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_employees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", (object)employee.City ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_employees.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd_employees.Parameters.Clear();
            }

            foreach (var c in employee.Competencies)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd_competencies = new SqlCommand(insert_competencies, conn))
                {
                    cmd_competencies.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", (object)empID ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_competencies.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", (object)c.Name ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_competencies.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShortCode", (object)c.ShortCode ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_competencies.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", (object)c.Status ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_competencies.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd_competencies.Parameters.Clear();
                }
            }

            foreach (var a in employee.NotAvailable)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd_available = new SqlCommand(insert_available, conn))
                {
                    cmd_available.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", (object)empID ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_available.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", (object)a.From ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_available.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", (object)a.To ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_available.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WeekDayIndex", (object)a.WeekDayIndex ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_available.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd_available.Parameters.Clear();
                }
            }

            foreach (var r in employee.Roles)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd_roles = new SqlCommand(insert_roles, conn))
                {
                    cmd_roles.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", (object)empID ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_roles.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Admin", (object)r.Admin ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_roles.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentId", (object)r.DepartmentId ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_roles.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee", (object)r.Employee ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_roles.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Planner", (object)r.Planner ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_roles.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd_roles.Parameters.Clear();
                }
            }

            foreach (var w in employee.HistoricalWages)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd_wages = new SqlCommand(insert_wages, conn))
                {
                    cmd_wages.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", (object)empID ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_wages.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", (object)w.StartDate ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_wages.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wage", (object)w.Wage ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd_wages.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd_wages.Parameters.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Above function works and get the data shipped to the sql server, but it literally takes forever.

So my question is, since i am by no means an expert here, what is the most efficient way(in regards to time) to accomplish the JSON to MSSQL transfer.

Comment: Instead of executing a single insert per *row*, use SqlBulkCopy to insert all of the data as a stream, using minimal logging. SqlBulkCopy uses the same mechanism as bcp and `BULK INSERT`

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos ill give that a go right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay is caused because the code executes one command per row. Given how small each row is, almost all the time is wasted on network round trips and logging of the individual operations.

You can use [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, to send all rows as a stream of records that will be inserted to the target table using minimal logging.

SqlBulkCopy expects a DataTable or DbDataReader. Instead of creating your own DataTable and double buffering all the rows, or writing your own data reader, you can use the [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) package to create an IDataReader from your collection :

```
using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) 
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(allEmployees, "Name", "EmployeeId", "Address1", "Phone", "Birthdate", "City", "Zip")) 
{ 
    bcp.DestinationTableName = "dtEmployees"; 
    bcp.WriteToServer(reader); 
}
```

If the property names and table fields don't match, you'll have to fill the [ColumnMappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.columnmappings(v=vs.110).aspx) property with the source and target names.

You'll have to flatten the nested collections with LINQ to get a collection that can be used with SqlBulkCopy, eg :

```
var allCompetencies = from employee in allEmployees
                      from competency in employee.Competencies
                      select new { employee.EmpoyeeID,
                                   competency.Name,
                                   competency.ShortCode,
                                   competency.Status};

using(var cmpBcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) 
using(var var cmpReader=ObjectReader.Create(allCompetencies,"EmployeeID","Name","ShortCode","Status"))
{ 
    cmpBcp.DestinationTableName = "dtCompetencies"; 
    cmpBcp.WriteToServer(cmpReader); 
}
```